# Angular 2 Starter Webpack looses @NgModule Decorator during bundling

Tags: angular, webpack, decorator, angular2-modules

Hi I've written an angular 2 sdk to facilitate access to our backend service. [Github](https://github.com/selfbits/selfbits-angular2-sdk)

Now I'm testing it on various popular templates and something strange happens with [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)'s template during bundling.

it "looses" or doesn't recognize the @NgModule Decorator and throws

> Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Interestingly the sdk works with [ng2-admin by akveo](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin), which is build on the angular2-webpack-starter

Below are some commented Code snippets to illustrate my problem

```
@NgModule({
    providers:SELFBITS_PROVIDERS,
    imports:[HttpModule]
})

export class SelfbitsAngularModule{
    static initializeApp(config:SelfbitsAppConfig):ModuleWithProviders{
        return {
            ngModule:SelfbitsAngularModule,
            providers:[
                { provide: SELFBITS_CONFIG, useValue: config }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

this is the custom Module, which initializes and provides the sdk's dependencies. In app.module.ts I then can run

```
imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    SelfbitsAngularModule.initializeApp(some_config_data)
  ],
```

I've compared the webpack config files from angular2-webpack-starter and ng2-admin. They are close to identical and nothing in particular pops up.

If I comment out the @NgModule Decorator the same error is shown in ng2-admin, thus my suspicion is that somehow it's not loaded or lost during the bundling process. Also following the error chain suggest the same

```
  if (importedMeta === null) {
    throw new Error("Unexpected " + _this._getTypeDescriptor(importedType) + " '" + stringify(importedType) + "' imported by the module '" + stringify(moduleType) + "'");
    }
```

The sdk also works with angular-cli beta15.